# Can't type in the input box of a "Short Answer" slide of Captivate 7 Flash output

Tags: flash, adobe-captivate

I have a short answer slide in an Adobe Captivate 7 file that is set as a survey type and it reports answers back via an internal server.

When I publish the project and view the Flash output ("Scalable HTML content" left unticked) I cannot type in the box at all.

I have checked that the text colour is not the same colour as the input box.
I have remade the particular slide a couple of times.

The HTML5 output works correctly, and I can type in the box.

I have the "Flash Player Version" requirement set to "Flash Player 10".

If anyone has any ideas that would be marvelous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to up the Flash Player Version requirement to "Flash Player 10.2". I can now type in the box successfully.

(I had Flash 11.9.900.117 installed on my machine to view with, if that makes any difference to this scenario).